# Add Final Price to admin product grid in Magento?

Tags: magento, admin

How can I add the "final price" (with all the catalog rules and special prices taken into account) to the product grid in the Magento admin?

UPDATE 10/12/2012
I am using v1.1.8 with a large number of customizations so I just did a fresh install of v.1.1.8 and added addFinalPrice() to the _prepareCollection() in the product grid, but now all I get is a semi-blank screen in the Manage Products admin.  Any ideas?

Comment: For any of them... depending on which one is selected.

Comment: Store ID selected how, the grid doesn't have a store switcher?  What about price rules that rely on customer and/or frontend state?

Comment: Using the "Choose Store View" above the grid.

Comment: Ah, right you are — I was looking at a system running in single store mode and/or an older version. That out of the way, what about price rules that rely on user and/or frontend state?

Comment: What should happen when you install an extension that does?

Comment: It won't happen.  I realize it's not ideal.  In this case we are using Magento for backend processing only and not using the Magento front end due to the clients existing setup issues.  It's a long story. :)

Answer (score 1):

final price depends on website and customer group, do you have business requirement which explain which of these prices needs  to  be shown? 
because in common case data in product grid depends on store.

In simple case, you can add price index table to collection of products and show data from it (In products collection already exists method `addPriceData`). (also you can implement customer-group switcher to be sure that you have covered all possible cases)

At link below example how to add new column to products grid
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/68993

simple example how to override products grid

step 1
override grid in config.xml of your module

```
<config>
...
    <global>
    ...
        <blocks>
        ...
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>Test_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        ...
        </blocks>
    ...
    </global>
...
</config>
```

step 2 implement your block

```
class Test_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    /**
     * get customer group id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getCustomerGroupId()
    {
        $customerGroupId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_group_id', 0);
        return $customerGroupId;
    }

    /**
     * prepare collection
     *
     * @return Test_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->addPriceData($this->_getCustomerGroupId(), $this->_getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare columns
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumnAfter('final_price',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Final Price'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $this->_getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'final_price',
            ), 'price');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

now, if you select store you will be able see price, for "All Store Views" this data is unavailable

Comment: Could I trouble you for a code sample for the final price for the addColumn() and collection modification?  Everything I have tried has failed horribly.

Comment: I do apologize, I failed to mention that I am using Magento v1.1.8 so addPriceData() hadn't been introduced yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->addPriceData()
```

will be helpful